# Where would I get the activity profile dataset for Lantus Solostar insulin, and for other diabetes treatments such as Metformin?

Tags: public-databases, visualization, data-download, modelling, public-dataset

I am working on a personal project for a better, more informed management of my own Diabetes Mellitus, Type 2 (aka "T2DM", or "T2D"). With some difficulty I am able to access and parse my Interstitial Glucose Level ("IGL") from my Continuous Glucose Monitor ("CGM"), and import the minute-by-minute data into a spreadsheet. I would like to be able to compare my IGL results to the activity profiles of both my prescribed insulin and my prescribed oral diabetes medications. I anticipate that such a comparison of the IGL and activity profiles of the treatments should give me an insight into the best times for administering my treatments. Later I will be adding further layers of comparison to this, such as my blood pressure, pulse, blood oxygen SpO₂ level, carbohydrate intake, exercise, etc to get a statistical view of which of these factors influence the IGL numbers the most, over time.

What I need first to be able to do all of this is a copy of the dataset for the activity profile of the insulin that I have been prescribed, the Lantus SoloStar 100ɪᴜ/mL pen. I have seen the graph of this data available online quite often, but I need to get the actual figures that the graphs are based on, in order to use them in my own modelling. If anyone knows where I might obtain this information, as a non-clinician myself, please let me know. Similarly, for a source of such activity profile data for common diabetes drugs such as Metformin and Gliclazide.

Also, if anyone knows of a better way to parse this information, including the raw data from the Abbott Freestyle Libre 2 with LibreView, please do let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You mention that you have seen the graph of the data you need online but you need the actual data.  Can you provide a link to the example graph? Ideally you would find a scientific article that shows that graph, and then look in the supplemental material for a table used to create the graph.